# RoR: How do I validate my pages when sometimes I have CSS links not in the HEAD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, validation, w3c

I get this error when using the w3 validator:  `document type does not allow element "link" here`

I mean, I know style links are suppossed to be in the head, but for an RoR project, it's more.. efficient? to only load what you need? cause, lets say, A stylesheet is loaded in a partial. and that partial is used on multiple pages. It makes sense, as far as DRYing things up goes, to include the stylesheet with the partial.

But it seems like DRYing things goes against W3C.

What do I do?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? In 3.1, I would recommend you let the asset pipeline compile your stylesheet partials into a single file.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.8. 3.1 is beautiful. but migration with a project this big isn't going to be fun. o.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting `<link>` elements into your content like that. You can use ERB's blocks to yield the content into another part of your layout template, like this:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'my_partial_styles' %>
<% end %>

<p>Your partial content...</p>
```

In your application layout, you can yield this content where it belongs:

```
<head>
<%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

Comment: I do use the stylesheet link tag, but anyway, will this work even if a partial is loaded via ajax as a 1 time thing? like, say, in a facebox of a different URL?

Comment: Yes. Anywhere you use the partial with the `content_for`, the block will be yielded to the head in your layout.

Comment: No. Then the document head is already downloaded to the browser. Honestly, I think you're going about this all wrong anyway. The CSS for a partial is hardly enough to warrant an additional HTTP round-trip: you should just include it in your main stylesheet instead of trying to make it more "efficient" (in your words) by sending it in a separate file.

Comment: hm. idk, When the style sheets get more organized, I'll see what I can do.